# What is the equivalent of angular-ui-router componentProvider in Angular 4 or angular-ui-router-ng2?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-ui-router

I have an AngularJS 1.6 app that loads a list of app modules fetched from the server. Every app has a different list of modules, so it would mean a lot of overhead code to create one unique route per module.

We are using ui-router, and it provides a really cool route config method called `componentProvider` which allows us to dynamically load a component pages on (in our case) the `$routeParams`.

Here is the working Angular 1.6 code:

```
//...
    .state('applications.apps.modules', {
      url: '/:moduleSlug',
      data: {
        addToSideMenu: false,
      },
      // create a dynamic component
      componentProvider: ($stateParams: StateParams) => {
        // This outputs "application-<name of module>"
        return `application${capitalizeFirstLetter(snakeToCamel($stateParams.moduleSlug))}`;
      },
      resolve: {
        application: (applications, $stateParams: StateParams) => {
          return applications.filter(app => app.slug === $stateParams.appSlug)[0];
        },
      },
    })
//...
```

This code will return a string `application-<name of module>`, and it allows us to load that module dynamically.

We're trying to find a way to do the same thing in that app but in Angular 4.

Any idea?

Comment: can you provide a link to the documentation that explains `componentProvider`?

Comment: Sure: https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/ng1.ng1statedeclaration.html#componentprovider